# Facebook Login for Intranet

Tags: authentication, facebook

How safe is Facebook Login? I'm currently building an intranet, for my small company. We're 10 employees, and no risk of them messing up from inside.

But is using Facebook Login safe for this? How much info does Facebook get? The pages after login will show stuff like Economy, and future plans. Our key elements of the company.

Comment: i can not really tell how safe facebook login is, and who knows what information they will be able to get, but i would not recommend to use facebook login to log into intranet. besides the question 'WHY!?', i would generally say that it is more secure, to use separate logins, especially for critical information like key elements of your company.

Comment: Alright. I was going to do this too. But the idea of making the login easier with facebook just hit me!

Comment: _"no risk of them messing up from inside"_ Somebody will always mess things from the inside, **always**. This is how most of these things happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no right or wrong answer to this, it all depends on what information you have to protect. If you are storing people's personal information or sensitive intellectual property on your intranet then using facebook logins are a bad idea because FB has no interest in security. FB does not enforce strong passwords. They allow very simple passwords and people are never required to change them. FB is written to make it easy for people to use so FB can profit from selling people's identities, they have no motivation to make it secure.

Ask yourself if you would rather have your salary details, address, ssn, employment history, plus the sum total of all the effort your company has ever produced to be protected by passwords that are likely to be your boss' birth date or kids name on a system that's ripe with identity theft. Or would you rather it be protected by a username/password scheme that enforces some level of complexity and the occasional change? hmmm, let me think....

In other words, if you have absolutely nothing to protect and don't care losing your job due to gross negligence then go for it!